# Django admin action for third party model

Tags: django, django-admin, extend

How can I add actions to the admin interface of a third party app?

Example: I want to have a custom action for the model `django.contrib.admin.Group`.

With "action" I mean the batch action of the admin list view of a model.

Related docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unregister the original model admin for `Group` model and then register it with your own `ModelAdmin`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group    

class MyGroupAdmin(GroupAdmin):
    actions = [...]

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, MyGroupAdmin)
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to add actions to the `ModelAdmin` from multiple apps then you have to directly access to the undocumented admin's registry:

```
def some_action(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    pass

admin.site._registry[Group].actions.append(some_action)
```

Comment: What should I do if two apps want to extend the same action list?