# Django: Reference a specific group from python code

Tags: python, django

We import data into a django application.

Each item is owned by a `django.contrib.auth.models.Group` instance.

Unfortunately the Group model has not slug.

I see two ways to wire the import code to the specific group:

- use the id of the group
- use the name of the group.

Both solutions are not nice: The ID is not good for unittesting and the name of the group (current solution) can be renamed by an admin. The rename would break future imports

How to solve this?

Comment: The general question would be: "How to reference database rows from code?"

Comment: You have two things a) a unique reference that does not change (id) and b) a human-readable name. For humans you need b) for code and computers you use a). What other feature would you need?

Comment: @KlausD. its hard to force the id of a group in a unittest in django. And the ID would be a "magic number". That's something I would like to avoid.

Comment: Well, the PK is a "magic number", that it's purpose. You should consider running your tests on defined test data from a fixture. Then it is easy to use the id in them.

Comment: @KlausD imagine I want to write a reusable app. Customer2 might already have a group with that fixed magic id.

Comment: This is why you run tests on a separate test configuration with test data and not on real production data.

Comment: @KlausD. imagine the magic id is `10` this works great for customer1 since he has only nine groups up to now. We install the reusable app for customer1. All is fine. Now comes customer2. He wants to use this app, too. But he has already a group with this id. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Admin can change the slug as well as the name :-)

BTW, you can prevent admin from changing the name by creating the [custom `ModelAdmin` for the `Group` model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29234049/548165).